# Adding css to the button where with the given value in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have multiple buttons on my page with css qtyButton:
I want to add the css to only button where value matches with the given value. I have used the following code but it is giving me error undefined in the alert box when i try to select the button value.

```
 <button class="qtyButton">1</button> 
 <button class="qtyButton">2</button>
 <button class="qtyButton">3</button>
```

```
$(document).on('click','.arrow',function(e){

            var curr_qty=$('#qty').val();
            var text = $('.qtyButton').filter(function () {
                  return this.value== curr_qty}).css('color', 'blue');
            });
```

Comment: What is curr_qty ?

Comment: And where are `.arrow` and `#qty` elements in your DOM?

Comment: This contains the value of another single text box that i have on my html page

Comment: You have set no value for your button - it has inner html or text but no value

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
$(document).on('click', function(e) {
  var curr_qty = 2
  $('.qtyButton').each(function() {
    if (parseInt($(this).text()) === curr_qty) $(this).css('color', 'blue')
  })
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button class="qtyButton">1</button>
<button class="qtyButton">2</button>
<button class="qtyButton">3</button>
```

Comment: @Pete Thanks. I didn't know what is the best approach for it. Fixed it now.

Comment: I didn't see the comment that instigated the change, but FYI - if this affected a large number of DOM elements, then it would be better to use `.filter` and apply the change once rather than than apply the change to each element which could generate a large number of DOM changes.

Answer (score 2):

You need to use `.innerText` instead `.value`

```
return this.innerText == curr_qty
```

Answer (score 2):

The issue is with `this.value` - the button doesn't have a `.value` - your HTML implies that you want to check the `.text()` of the button (or use `this.innerText` for more efficiency):

```js
$("#clickme").click(function(e) {
  var curr_qty = $('#qty').val();
  $('.qtyButton').filter(function() {
    return $(this).text() == curr_qty
  }).css('color', 'red');  // changed to red as blue wasn't clear enough
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type='text' id='qty' value="1" />
<button class="qtyButton">1</button>
<button class="qtyButton">2</button>
<button class="qtyButton">3</button>
<hr/>
<button id='clickme'>click me</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have, somewhere in your DOM, a `<button>` with the class `arrow`, and a number `<input>` with the ID `qty`.

I want to respect your `return this.value== curr_qty` line, so I added `value` attributes to your `.qtyButton` elements.

```html
 <button class="arrow" type="button">.arrow</button>
 <input type="number" id="qty" value="1">

 <br />

 <button class="qtyButton" value="1" >1</button> 
 <button class="qtyButton" value="2" >2</button>
 <button class="qtyButton" value="3" >3</button>
```

```
$(document).on('click','.arrow',function(e) {
    $('.qtyButton').css('color', '');

    var curr_qty = $('#qty').val();
    var text = $('.qtyButton').filter(function () {
        return this.value == curr_qty;
    }).css('color', 'blue');
});
```

I added a color reset of all elements before your logic.